# QML Canvas clipping - non rectangular possible?

Tags: qml, qt5

Is it possible to display non rectangular items in an app?

The top right edge of each element is clipped:

[image]

I turned off clipping on the canvas element and set the clipping
region of the context. I even allowed for the stroke drawing outside
the path. Here's what I'm using to draw it:

```
Canvas
{
    //id: root
    // canvas size
    height: parent.height - 8
    width: height
    anchors.top: parent.top + 4
    clip: false
    z: index + 1
    // handler to override for drawing
    onPaint:
    {
        // get context to draw with
        var ctx = getContext("2d")
        ctx.reset();

        // path that includes 1 pixel margin on all sides
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.moveTo( 8, 0 )
        ctx.lineTo( width + 4, 0 )
        ctx.lineTo( width - 4, height )
        ctx.lineTo( 0, height )
        ctx.closePath()
        ctx.clip();

        // setup the stroke
        ctx.lineWidth = 2
        ctx.strokeStyle = "white"
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.moveTo( 9, 1 )
        ctx.lineTo( 9 + width, 1 )
        ctx.lineTo( 1 + width, height - 1 )
        ctx.lineTo( 1, height - 1 )
        ctx.closePath()
        ctx.fillStyle = (roleStatus.toLowerCase().indexOf("success")!==-1) ? "green" : "red"
        ctx.fill()
        ctx.stroke()
    }
}
```

This will be used on Windows and android.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a way to draw outside the bounds of the item. I was able to achieve the effect I wanted though. I drew the polygon within the bounds of the item and set the 'spacing' property of the ListView to a negative value. This overlaps the drawn items to achieve the desired look:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes... You can use PaintedItem to paint directly on items using Native Paint tools from C++ like `QPainterPath`

check out http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-customitems-painteditem-example.html

the reason that your canvas is clipping is due to the fact that you are drawing  width + 4 which should be `(width - 8)`, but since you move to `(8,0)` first, then you end up drawing an extra 4 pixels too far. try either moving the item over 4 pixels by doing   moveTo(4,0)  or make the line shorter by doing  just width instead of `width + 4`

Also check out  :  `anchors.fill: parent`  which will work better in your case most likely.

The way that I avoid crazy bugs like this is by not ever hard coding width, height, x or y into my application..  instead use  percentages such as

`(parent.width * 0.25)`  to get 1/4 of the parent

Here's ONE way you could fix your code...

```
Canvas
{
    //id: root
    // canvas size
    height: parent.height * 0.95
    width: height
    anchors.top: parent.top
    clip: false
    z: index + 1
    // handler to override for drawing
    onPaint:
    {
        // get context to draw with
        var ctx = getContext("2d")
        ctx.reset();

        // path that includes 1 pixel margin on all sides
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.moveTo( width * 0.1, 0 )
        ctx.lineTo( width * 0.9, 0 )
        ctx.lineTo( width * 0.7, height )
        ctx.lineTo( 0, height )
        ctx.closePath()
        ctx.clip();
        /* etc etc */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am intentionally "coloring outside the lines" and trying to get rid of the clipping. I'll try a QPaintedItem class and see if that works.

Comment: QQuickPaintedItem also clips to the size of the item. FYI: These are displayed by a QML ListView. The clipping settings for it don't have any effect on the delegate items it draws.

Comment: The way I would do it would be to create a QQuickPaintedItem  and then use  setCompositionMode()  and set it to `Source Atop` and make the item 8 pixels larger than the button..

Comment: Or you could just set the z-index of each item so that they appear in reverse order and that will pretty much do what you want it to do without the need for any complex code

Comment: Or have no background color at all and let the canvases overlap and have a single black rectangle behind it all

Comment: I tried using the index role of the listview as the z index. Didn't work